# Power BI - Date slicer not working on merge queries

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hi I have a report that has a left join merge queries based on report name so i can count the total number of executions of a particular report, but it not refreshing the table once a select a relative date from the date slicer. Is it because the total execution is aggregated by report name? or is there i way i can add the execution date in the merge query?

[image]

[image]

Merge Queries List of fields (Merge New Query - Left join on ReportName). How do i show TimeStart from Execution query to Merge query?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a list of all the columns in both the queries you are trying to merge?

It seems that your final query does is not having date column. As to why slicer is not working, it can depend on a lot of things including the data model. If you are just using merged query that does not include date, that is possibly the reason.

Comment: I added a field schema in original post.